# Error al crear proyecto en maven en java

Tags: windows, java-swing, maven

Al crear un proyecto de maven en neatbeans 8.2 dey en Maven - java application - siguiente, en la segunda pantalla aparece **project folder cannot be located on UNC path**, vi una nota que decia que agregara a meven al path  de windows y ya lo hice pero sigue marcando el mismo error  [image: Mensaje de maven en windows y error en la pantalla de creacion]

Comment: Buenas, mira esto a ver si te puede ayudar, espero que si. [enlace] (https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=146948)  Saludos y bienvenido

Comment: muchas gracias @josanangel deja lo checo

Comment: Gracias @josanangel el error estaba en que tenia que agregar la ruta donde esta mi maven ejemplo C:\dev esta en mi unidad c y sin problemas me dejo crear el proyecto